# How to bundle with webpack for angular 4 module lazily without routing and url changed

Tags: angular

this.loader.load('app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule').then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory) => {
            const entryComponent = (moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
            const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.inj);

```
        const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);
        this.container.createComponent(compFactory);
    });
```

Comment: That question only refers to projects built on systemjs, however I am not sure why don't you want to use routing, it's a lot easier and cleaner way.

Comment: mine is widget based application it will get load with iframes so i cant use routing. thanks for helping.